# bosh Invalid SSL Cert

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I've installed Pivotal's Ops Manager. When I try to point bosh at it's director I get:

```
$ bosh target 10.120.7.11
Target set to 'p-bosh'
Invalid SSL Cert. Use --ca-cert option when setting target to specify SSL certificate
```

The certs were generated automatically by the install. How can get past this error?

Comment: Use the generated (selfsigned?) certificate and pass it using the `--ca-cert` parameter?

Comment: If you click on the tile where you configure BOSH and the IaaS settings, there should be a tab to see credentials.  Should be able to find the CA cert there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Ops Mgr, the "root_ca_cert.yml' is located in /var/tempest/workspaces/default. Use that as follows ..

```
$ bosh target --ca-cert /var/tempest/workspaces/default/root_ca_cert.yml <director-ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, This appears to be happening in BOSH CLI v1. They fixed it in CLI V2 (as of Sep 2017)

If you are using CLI V1 pointing against a BOSH director, then make sure you mention the flag "--ca-cert" before director IP. The reason is they treat ca-cert as global flag in V1.